# Spring Boot with GORM gives LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, spring-boot

I've used Spring.io's tutorial [Accessing Data with GORM](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm/) to try to use Spring-Boot together with **GORM**.

The basics work quite well and I'm impressed :-)

I'm going a little bit further and from a Spring controller trying to load a lazy child collection.

Example:

```
def customer = Customer.get(id)
if (customer) {
    def invoices = customer.invoices // lazy hasMany
    return new ResponseEntity(invoices, HttpStatus.OK)
} else {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
}
```

This gives the dreaded Hibernate lazy loading exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: my.com.Customer.invoices, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

In standard Spring application I would solve this by registering the `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.

Shouldn't Spring Boot `autoconfigure` this automatically?

Maybe my setup is incorrect?

I've basically only added the following dependencies:

```
compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.1.0.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

Comment: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11597